# windows installation, diskpart I/O device error

Tags: windows, windows-10, diskpart

I am trying to install windows 10 on my ssd 240g in laptop.
If I try to install it with the same bootable usb on virtual machine - I runs smoothly.
But, When I try the other option of choosing a disk (empty without any partitions) to install it, I receive this error - 0x80300002.
I googled this error, and I saw that I need to run this commands in the cmd to make it run:

`diskpart`,

`select disk (installation disk number)` ,

`clean`,

`exit`

I believe here starts my problem, cause something wired happens at that part:
When running `clean` at the first time I got I/O device error.
On the second time an on, it suddenly runs with no problem. (Important to note - if I close the cmd and go with the same processes again, I get the error again at the first try, but not on the second)
I saw an alternative solution that says I need to run `convert gpt` after the `clean` command, I got again the same error above.

Comment: I/O device errors doesn't seems good. Can you please check the SMART status of the SSD?

Comment: I checked already... I run ``` wmic diskdrive get status ``` and got status OK

Comment: not all errors are detected by SMART. I'd try Crystal Disk Info to read out all the SMART values. Any abnormal values that are not seen as errors will be here too.

Comment: I have trouble to open the screws to get the ssd. there any other way?

Comment: You do not want to open up the screws. Crystal Disk Info is software you can download

Comment: I know, but I have laptop without operation system. So I have to open the laptop and connect the ssd to another computer